# MySQL query getting hanged and had to kill the process

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE APA_Pended_Demand APD
INNER JOIN APA_Generic_Demand_Details AGD
    ON APD.demandID = AGD.demandID
SET APD.genericDemandId = AGD.genericDemandId
WHERE 
APD.isPend = 1
AND COALESCE(AGD.genericDemandId, '') != ''
AND APD.reactivateDate > UTC_TIMESTAMP() 
AND AGD.status < 300 
AND APD.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
```

I am using the above code for update about 3,00,000 rows and when I am trying to do that we are getting hanged or timeout error.The indexes are properly used but getting hanged.

So can anyone please help me to get this sorted out

Comment: have you tried this query as select statement. Do a select of this two columns (used in set statement) and see if you are able to do a select. If it works then update will work.Optimize you select and then convert it to update.

Comment: Set all blank genericDemandIds to NULL

Answer (score 0):

Once you've removed the blank values, I suspect that covering indexes on
(demandID,isPend,reactivateDate) and (demandID,genericDemandId,status) will help, instead of whatever you've currently got